# How do I post an HTML class into a mongoDB collection using express/mongoose and client-side JS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, post, express

First off my programming knowledge is entirely on the front-end, but I'm experimenting with node, express, mongoose, and mongodb.  I'm using someone else's template to try and build an app the right way, but I'm lost when connecting the dots.  I have the following jade:

```
  form(method='post', action="/post/comment/" + post.id)
    textarea(name='text')
    input(type='submit', value='Save')
```

Combined with this from the routes/posts.js file

```
 app.post("/post/comment/:id", loggedIn, function (req, res, next) {
    var id = req.param('id');
    var text = req.param('text');
    var author = req.session.user;

    Comment.create({
        post: id
      , text: text
      , author: author
     }, function (err, comment) {
      if (err) return next(err);

      res.redirect("/post/" + id);
    });
  });
```

and this is models/comment.js :

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var ObjectId = mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId;
var createdDate = require('../plugins/createdDate');

var schema = mongoose.Schema({
    text: { type: String, trim: true, validate: validateText }
  , post: { type: ObjectId, index: true }
  , author: String
})

function validateText (str) {
  return str.length < 250;
}

schema.plugin(createdDate);

module.exports = mongoose.model('Comment', schema);
```

Now this works fine, for submitting a comment and saving it in the DB.  Problem is, is that I don't want to save a comment, but HTML after a function has manipulated it.  So I tried:

```
var everything =  $('.whatever').html();
$.post("/post/comment/:id", everything, 
  function(){
    console.log('html saved!')
  }
)
```

But I got a `POST http://localhost:3000/post/comment/:id 500 (Internal Server Error)`  Now I'm aware that I probably don't have the `id` variable so I tried pasting in the number that is in the url, and that seemed to go through without error, but than didn't show up in the DB.  I'm aware that this may not be a specific question, and that I may be going about this entirely wrong but any general direction would be much appreciated.    Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to have a number of problems here. Try taking a look at the following:

1. Your router is set to receive posts to "/post/comment/:id", but your post in the last code block is posting to "/post/comments/:id", where comments is plural. This will likely result in a 404. (Check the networks tab of your browser javascript console. It may be silently failing without you realizing it).
2. Your 500 error is likely coming from the fact that you directly posted ":id", instead of an actual identifier. Many node apps will have an app.param() block set up to validate these parameters, and your friend's template is likely breaking when it doesn't get a number it expects.
3. The data that you post must match the schema of the model you're saving it to. Any keys that aren't named in the schema will be stripped prior to saving, and in your case, if no keys match, it will just be a default comment instance, and won't save at all.

Hope that helps!